# How can I separate time-series data into segments of continuous data according to a range of values in another column

Tags: r, datetime, subset, segment

I would like to separate a time series data into different segments (each being a different dataframe) according to the values of another column. For example:

```
#Generate a data frame of hourly precipitation and water level. 
install.packages("lubridate")  
library(lubridate)
df<-data.frame(date_time=ymd_hms(seq(c(ISOdate(2000,3,20)), by = "hour", length.out = 365)), precip= sample(0:10,365,replace=T), water_level=sample(-50:50,365,replace=T)))
```

I would like to make subsets of the time series data for when the water level is negative, keeping the date time value as it is (parsed using lubridate) along with the water level and precipitation variables for that continuous time range.

Comment: So simply `split(df, df$water_level >= 0)`?

Comment: @Sotos Thank you for your answer. Actually I require a continuous time series for each subset, so the moment the water level is positive, the dataset needs to split up until that point, and then start checking the water level again for when it is negative, include again all the continuous negative values of water level and split again when the water level is positive. "Splitting" the data in this case does not achieve this because there are time gaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a variable to group between positive and negative values, and split. In your case, we create a logical vector `df$water_level >= 0` with greater and less than 0 values. The way to create sequential groups between them is to take the cumulative sum of the difference, when that difference is NOT 0, meaning that the next value is FALSE (or TRUE).

```
split(df, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(df$water_level >= 0) != 0)))
```

which gives,

> ```
> $`1`
>             date_time precip water_level
> 1 2000-03-20 12:00:00      8          45
>
> $`2`
>             date_time precip water_level
> 2 2000-03-20 13:00:00      9         -12
>
> $`3`
>             date_time precip water_level
> 3 2000-03-20 14:00:00      4           9
> 4 2000-03-20 15:00:00      0          13
> 5 2000-03-20 16:00:00      8          34
>
> $`4`
>             date_time precip water_level
> 6 2000-03-20 17:00:00      1         -20
> ...
> ...
> ```

Comment: that's great. It's working. Thank you so much. But do you think you could explain how " cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(df$water_level >= 0) != 0))" is functioning to make grouping factor? I am not quite sure how this is working.

Comment: Yes let me add some explanation

Comment: Also try and break it down and run it bit by bit. That will reveal the way it works

Comment: Brilliantly explained! Thank you so much. Yes, indeed. :)